# difference between the value returned by count and status api by elasticsearch

Tags: count, elasticsearch, status

Currently I'm counting the number of documents in an index in elasticsearch.

When I used count api, it returned:

```
{
  "count" : 86873223,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 29,
    "successful" : 29,
    "failed" : 0
  }
}
```

However when I used status api, it returned:

```
{
  ...,
  "docs" : {
        "num_docs" : 333638298,
        "max_doc" : 429446807,
        "deleted_docs" : 95808509
      },
  ...,
}
```

I'm wondering why there is a huge difference between the two.

Any hint?

Btw, I'm using the nested objects heavily. Could this be the reason?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using nested docs?

Comment: @rkrahl yeah I'm using nested objects a lot in this mapping.

Comment: I think so. Each nested object is internally separate document. See http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each nested document is a internal Lucene document by itself.
Hence you will see this number added to the entire document set.